# Moving tempdb from shared to local drive in a failover cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, clustering, failover, tempdb

We have an existing failover cluster that I would like to have the tempdb in local drive. I'm not sure how to proceed. My thought process is below:

- Create two drives on each node one for tempdb and one for temp log with same name on each node. Give the SQL Server service account full control permission on the folders that will have the files.
- Move the tempdb files by failing over to the active node and moving the tempdb files, this has to be done on all the nodes.

Is there anything else I need to do? Do I need to rerun the cluster validation or add the local disks to dependency? Will this break the cluster?

Comment: As long as both nodes have the same path and permissions locally for where you want to put the files you be able to simply do a modify on each file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-system-databases?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: So for example i connect to the sql cluster network name and change the tempdb on the active node 1 and then failover to node 2  will there be any problem starting up on node 2

Comment: As long as the same path exists on node 2 and the account sql server is using has write permissions it should failover without any issues